# Rust serenity discord: How to get members from a voice channel?

Tags: rust, discord

I'm trying to get members from a voice channel like I did it in Python using discord.py

```py
# Python
def getDiscordUsers():
    json = {name: [] for name in names}

    for i in range(0, 3):
        channel = bot.get_channel(channels[i])
        members = channel.members
        for member in members:
            # selfMuted = member.voice.self_mute
            if member.bot:
                continue
            if member.nick == None:
                json[names[i]].append(member.name)
            else:
                json[names[i]].append(member.nick)

    return json
```

I'm wondering how to pass the context and call the function whenever I want to.

```rust
pub async fn call_me(ctx: &Context) {
    let members = get_users_from_voice(ctx, 12345).await.unwrap();
    // for memeber in members { println!("{}", member.nick) }
}

async fn some() -> ... {
    json!(call_me(ctx).await?)
}
```

I can only think of getting a channel from an id

```rust
pub async fn get_users_from_voice(ctx: &Context) {
    let channel = ctx.http.get_channel(834776536489656345).await.unwrap();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [Guild](https://docs.rs/serenity/0.10.9/serenity/model/guild/struct.Guild.html) struct you can get all the channels pertaining to a Guild with `.channels.values()`. This will give you an iterator with which you can then match the channel kind to the voice type and then do something with it.
In short it would look something like this:

```rust
pub fn call_me(guild: Guild) {
    for channel in guild.channels.values() {
        if let channel.kind = ChannelType::Voice {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```